# Swinnerton-Dyer passed away?

Tags: discussion

[His wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Swinnerton-Dyer) has been updated to say that he passed away recently. Are there any other sources confirming that? Thanks.

If it is more appropriate for another stackexchange site, please feel free to move the question there.

Comment: For what it's worth, that edit seems to have been made by someone in the city of Béziers in France (though could be through a VPN, or via Tor, or...). Others may be able to glean information from that fact.

Comment: Properly speaking, though, asking whether or not this is a suitable question to ask on MO means this could go on meta.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no longer relevant (the question asked whether some information, now confirmed, is reliable)

Comment: maybe ask https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryan_John_Birch ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer seems to be yes (from private sources close to Sir Peter Swinnerton-Dyer).

Comment: Thanks for confirming, though it is not pleasant.

Comment: Just so there is a definite link: https://www.caths.cam.ac.uk/about-us/news-and-events/professor-sir-peter-swinnerton-dyer-bt-kbe-frs-1927-2018

Comment: Obituary at https://www.trin.cam.ac.uk/news/sir-peter-swinnerton-dyer-1927-2018/